# I obtain a wrong result for this integral (Gauss's Law)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, electromagnetism, divergence-theorem

### Defining the problem

I (believe) am getting a wrong result when I try to prove Gauss's Law for a charge $q$ **inside** a closed surface $\partial \Omega$. The (mathematical) problem goes like this:

Given a closed surface $\partial \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, the constants $k_e, q \in \mathbb{R}$ and the vector field $\mathbf{E} = k_e q \mathbf{r} / |\mathbf{r}|^3$, calculate the total *(electric) flux* of the vector field $\mathbf{E}$ through the surface $\partial \Omega$:
$$
 \Phi_e = \iint_{\partial \Omega} \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}
$$
Where $d\mathbf{A}$ is just the differential area on the closed surface $\partial \Omega$. (I couldn't render the closed surface integral $\unicode{x222F}$ using Mathjax, sorry).

---

### Trying to solve it

Defining $\Omega$ as all the points inside the closed surface and using the divergence theorem, we can write the integral as:
$$
\Phi_e = \iiint_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}\,dV
$$

Using the Einstein's summation convention and cartesian coordinates to represent $\mathbf{r}$ as $\mathbf{r} = x_i \mathbf{e}_i $, the divergence $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}$ is expressed as :

$$
\nabla\cdot \mathbf{E} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{k_e q x_i}{|\mathbf{r}|^3} = k_e q \left( x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}|^3} + \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}|^3}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} x_i  \right) = k_e q \left( x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}|^3} + \frac{3}{|\mathbf{r}|^3} \right)
$$
For  $\partial |\mathbf{r}|^{-3} / \partial x_i$ we have:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{1}{\left(\mathbf{r\cdot r}\right)^{3/2}} = -\frac{3}{2}(\mathbf{r\cdot r})^{-5/2} (2\mathbf{r})\cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial x_i} = -\frac{3\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|^5} \cdot \frac{\partial x_j \mathbf{e}_j}{\partial x_i} = -\frac{3x_i}{|\mathbf{r}|^5}
$$
Substituting back into the expression for $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}$, we have:
$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E} = k_e q \left( -\frac{3x_i x_i}{|\mathbf{r}|^5} + \frac{3}{|\mathbf{r}|^3} \right) =  k_e q \left( -\frac{3|\mathbf{r}|^2}{|\mathbf{r}|^5} + \frac{3}{|\mathbf{r}|^3} \right) =  k_e q \left( -\frac{3}{|\mathbf{r}|^3} + \frac{3}{|\mathbf{r}|^3} \right)  = 0 
$$

Substituting on the integral for $\Phi_e$ will just give $0$, too.

### Wrong result:

Here is where I know there is a mistake:
Although with the given electric field $\mathbf{E}$ the charge $q$ is placed in the origin, I haven't said anything about the closed surface $\partial \Omega$: I have not said if the closed surface contains or not the origin, this is, I haven't said if the charge is inside the closed surface or not.

Gaus's Law states that if the charge is inside $\partial \Omega$, then $\Phi_e = 4\pi k_e q$ (If the origin is inside $\partial \Omega$, for the given $\mathbf{E}$)

If the charge is outside, then $\Phi_e = 0$. (If the origin is outside $\partial \Omega$ for the given $\mathbf{E}$)

So,

1. Since I am getting $0$ as an answer, in which moment I am assuming that the charge is outside?
2. How can I get the two results, $0$ and $4\pi k_e q$?

Comment: If I remember correctly it u get 0 if the charge is assumed out of the closed surface, u get the second if the charge is assumed inside of the closed surface

Comment: Your math is actually ok for all r>0. Problem is this is a 'point' charge with a singularity at r=0. Divergence of E is 0 everywhere except at r=0. This wiki page has a couple of 'derivations' of Gauss' law from the coulomb law. One by using the delta function. Two by assuming the charge is distributed over a sphere and taking the limit of the radius of the sphere to 0: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law

Comment: @AmeetSharma Oh, I neglected the singularity at $0$ of the $\mathbf{E}$ field. Ignoring its value is more or less like assuming the charge is outside the closed surface, so indeed I'll have 0 as a result. Taking it into account, it's like assuming the charge is inside the closed surface. Working with an infinitesimal sphere containing that charge is the reason for that $\pi$ factor to appear. Thanks for your comment, it helped me a lot.